# How to use turn.js in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm a beginner in android so please excuse me if my question is foolish.
I want to implement `turn.js` library in android webview for showing book.As I read about `WebView` it can run `javascript` so I wonder is there anyway to use `turn.js` in android. I've referred this link  [turn.js website](http://www.turnjs.com/)

JS code:

```
<div id="flipbook">
<div class="hard"> Turn.js </div>
<div class="hard"></div>
<div> Page 1 </div>
<div> Page 2 </div>
<div> Page 3 </div>
<div> Page 4 </div>
<div class="hard"></div>
<div class="hard"></div>
   </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    autoCenter: true
   });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to load web-page with script to WebView.

I used Monocle lib to show books so I placed html, js and css files into assets folder [image]

Here is my mono.html
You are using turn.js library so you may find sample web page at library samples.

```
<head>
<!-- Include the Monocle library and styles -->
<script src="scripts/monocore.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/monocore.css" />
<script src="scripts/monoctrl.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/monoctrl.css" />
<style>
    #reader { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
</style>

<script>
    function createBookTitle(reader, contactListeners) {
    var bt = {}
    bt.createControlElements = function () {
      cntr = document.createElement('div');
      cntr.className = "bookTitle";
      runner = document.createElement('div');
      runner.className = "runner";
      runner.innerHTML = reader.getBook().getMetaData('title');
      cntr.appendChild(runner);
      if (contactListeners) {
        Monocle.Events.listenForContact(cntr, contactListeners);
      }
      return cntr;
    }
    reader.addControl(bt, 'page');
    return bt;
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="reader"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
Monocle.Events.listen(
    window,
    'load',
    function () {
      var readerOptions = {
        panels: Monocle.Panels.Magic
      };

      Monocle.Reader('reader', bookData, readerOptions, function (rdr) 
{
        window.reader5 = rdr;
        var toc = Monocle.Controls.Contents(rdr);
        rdr.addControl(toc, 'popover', { hidden: true });
        createBookTitle(
          rdr,
          {
            start: function () {
              rdr.showControl(toc);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }
  );



 </script>

</body>
```

After that you may show this page at web view like that

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/mono.html");
```

and the last step is load book content into this page. I wrote a helper that transforms book file to JS book object https://github.com/joseph/Monocle/wiki/Book-data-object with "javascript:" prefix. So it looks like "javascript: var bookData = {...."
and load this script

```
webView.loadUrl(bookData);
```